# how to use if statement to test membership of a string

Tags: string, if-statement, membership

I'm having trouble understanding my logic in a simple Python statement. I'm trying to use 'not in' to test whether 's' or '5' is a part of the input but when I use either of them the same print statement is executed which says 's or 5 is not included'. Here is my code:

```
myinput = input('Enter input here')
if 's' or '5' not in myinput:
    print('s or 5 is not included')
else:
    print('s or 5 is included')
```

Could someone help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Scott Hunter

```
if ('s' not in myinput) and ('5' not in myinput):
    print('s or 5 is not included')
else:
    print('s or 5 is included')
```

De Morgan's law states that **not (A or B) = not A and not B**

In your example, A = 's' is in myinput, and B = '5' is in myinput

Comment: This code snippet works as long as I don't include the 'is' within the 'if' brackets

Comment: My bad, just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

(Am certain this is a duplicate, but could not find it.)

"Neither 's' nor '5' are in myinput" is logically equivalent to "('s' is not in myinput) and ('5' is not in myinput)".  (See DeMorgan's Law.)